# What is the name or Unicode for this symbol (similar to ₰, Dutch, called Krul)

Tags: symbols, unicode

This is the symbol I mean, I think it is named a 'Krul': 
[image: Krul symbol]

I found this symbol (U+20B0, ₰, German Penny Sign) but it is **not** the one I am looking for.
[image: U+20B0 german pfennig]

In the Netherlands it is generally used to indicate that something has been done correctly, like a check.

I would like to know the unicode and/or the name.

Comment: Note that if you do not get an answer here, you should raise the issue on the Unicode mailing list.

Comment: Noted, I will give it some more time and than do that :) also thanks for re-formatting my question.

Comment: Out of interest, which end (upper or lower) do you start drawing it from?

Comment: @OrangeDog One line from the bottom left, as shown in animation linked [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313281/how-to-make-a-krul-unofficial-dutch-symbol-for-ok).

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the name is 'Approval curl' and there is no unicode.

In The Netherlands the naming differs, so there should be differnt English words too if English speakers would use the symbol I guess. But if I had to choose, ´approval curl´ would be my choice.

The appearance of the sign also differs too. See [here](http://prntscr.com/8abqoc) a printscreen of two slighlty different 'krullen' (the Dutch plural of 'krul'). I copied those from 'www.goeievraag.nl/maatschappij/onderwijs/vraag/85664/teken-genoemd-vooral-scholen-gebruikt'.

Some of the Dutch naming I found on the internet: vink(je), krul(letje), paraafje, slingertje, goedje, plusje, puntje, bonusje. See also [here](http://www.goeievraag.nl/maatschappij/onderwijs/vraag/85664/teken-genoemd-vooral-scholen-gebruikt) the comment made by madelief2100.

Some additional info for non-Dutch residents:
The usage is comparable with the checkmark. I've seen it used by teachers to state something is done, done correctly or done good. When I went to high school (that is around your 13th year of age) I haven't seen it used by teachers anymore. I assume it has some childish connotation to it.

Comment: Actually, my teachers used it all throughout my high school period (13-17) and maybe even at the university.

Answer (score 3):

This character has strong similarities to [deleatur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dele), which is used in proofreading, however to mark that something shall be deleted:

[image: Deleatur]

Comment: It looks very similar indeed! Thanks! It is very interesting to see that a symbol used in one context to mark correct answers, is used in a different context for deleting.